# Laravel 5.1 "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

After completing my project in localhost, I had upload my project to the server suppose the url is  www.example.com. I upload the entire project to the public_html and movie all the file from public to the root i.e public_html and edit index.php to point to the bootstrap autoload.php and app.php . But when I try to access the url like www.example.com, I get error like

This webpage has a redirect loop

**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

My routes.php is

```
<?php 

Route::get('/dashboard',array(
    'as'    => 'dashboard',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@index'
));


Route::get('/dashboard/activate_user', array(
    'as'    => 'active-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@activate_user'
));


Route::post('/dashboard/activate_user',array(
    'as'    => 'active-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@activate_user_post'
)); 

/**
 * User routes
 */
//display the form to add user 
Route::get('/dashboard/create_user',array(
    'as'    => 'create-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@create_user'
));
//insert data into db
Route::post('/dashboard/create_user', array(
    'as'    => 'create-user-post',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@create_user_post'
));

//list user 
Route::get('/dashboard/list_users',array(
    'as'    => 'list-user',
    'uses'  =>'UserController@list_users'
));
//view user
Route::get('dashboard/view_users/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'view-user',
    'uses'  =>'UserController@view_users'
));

//delete user 
Route::get('dashboard/delete_user/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'delete-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@delete_user'
));

//edit user 
Route::get('dashboard/edit_user/{id}', array(
    'as'    => 'edit-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@edit_user'
));
Route::post('dashboard/edit_user/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'edit-user',
    'uses'  => 'UserController@edit_user_post'
)); 



/* (Painfully) Using laravel magic */
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('dashboard/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');


//service controller 
Route::get('dashboard/add_service','ServiceController@create');
Route::post('dashboard/add_service','ServiceController@store');
Route::get('dashboard/list_service','ServiceController@index');
Route::get('dashboard/edit_service/{id}','ServiceController@edit');
Route::post('dashboard/edit_service/{id}','ServiceController@update');
Route::get('dashboard/delete_service/{id}','ServiceController@destroy');



//profile controller 
Route::get('/dashboard/profile/edit/org/{id}',array(
    'as'=> 'edit-org',
    'uses'=>'ProfileController@editOrg'
));

Route::post('/dashboard/profile/edit/org/{id}',array(
    'as'=> 'edit-org-post',
    'uses'=>'ProfileController@updateOrg'
));

Route::get('/dashboard/profile/edit/person/{id}',array(
    'as'=> 'edit-person',
    'uses'=>'ProfileController@editPerson'
));

Route::post('/dashboard/profile/edit/person/{id}',array(
    'as'=> 'edit-person-post',
    'uses'=>'ProfileController@updatePerson'
));

Route::get('/dashboard/profile/edit/logo/{id}',array(
    'as'    => 'edit-logo',
    'uses'  => 'ProfileController@deleteImage'

));


Route::get('/search',array(
    'as'    => 'search-result',
    'uses'  => 'SearchLogController@index'
));

Route::post('/agent-search-log',array(
    'as'    => 'agent-search-log',
    'uses'  => 'SearchLogController@agentSearchLog'
));

/* route to display the search log graph **/
Route::get('/search/graph',array(
    'as'    => 'search-result-graph',
    'uses'  => 'SearchLogController@searchFlightGraph'
));

Route::post('/search/graph/agent',array(
    'as'    => 'search-result-agent-graph',
    'uses'  => 'SearchLogController@searchAgentFlightGraph'
));


Route::post('/search-from-to',array(
    'as'=> 'download-search-log',
    'uses'=> 'SearchLogController@downloadFromTo'
));



/* excel route */
Route::get('/search/download',array(
    'as'    => 'search-download-excel',
    'uses'  => 'SearchLogController@downloadExcel'
));
```

Comment: Clear cookies and site data of the browser you are using. Try accessing the domain with another browser and see if the same thing happens or not.

Comment: I don't see any routes which would match `www.example.com/`. Where is your `'/'` route?

Comment: If route is not found it will give RoutenotFoundexception  but here error is different

Comment: try put Route::get('/', function(){ return "hello" }); see if its appear. if its not show hello, recheck your bootstrap location on index.php is it correct.

Comment: I had tried that too .. but not solve my problem. After doing so many research I found where my problem was . The server has PHP version 5.4 which is not supported by laravel i.e laravel5.1 support PHP >= 5.5.9. So, I think I get error like that. Thanks for trying to solve my problem.